# Accessing Elements in an Array c++

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers

I am using a templated class and creating an array to store values. I need to overload the [] operator in this array and this is where I am having issues.

```
template <class TYPE>
class ArrayList : public ListInterface<TYPE>
{
public:
    TYPE * aL = new TYPE[25];
}
```

For my overloaded operater for [] I have the following:

```
    TYPE & operator[] (int num) const  //will addd throw std out of range
{
    return aL[num];
}
```

However, when I use this operator later in the program it doesn't return the value at that specific index.

```
void insertAt(int index, const TYPE & newEntry)
    //throw (std::out_of_range)...
{
    aL[index] = newEntry;
    TYPE a = aL[index]; //use this to see what it is returning
}
```

I used the variable "a" as a debugging tool to see what is returned for aL[index] and I get the following int held inside of "a" : -858993460. I am sure this must be a simple error, I have searched for a very long time to figure out why this behavior is occuring but have not been able to get to the bottom of it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What value is in `newEntry`? Please provide [mcve]. You have the whole sources and can not resolve the issue, but want us to be psychics.

Comment: `aL[index]` does not actually call your `operator[]` since `aL` is an array of `TYPE`, not a `ListInterface` object.

Comment: Ok. Let's say newEntry is an int value of 4. Shouldn't the "a" variable be holding 4?

Comment: No. The `a` is not used, and could be optimized or be out of scope when you try to watch it in your debugger.